# did the java update in january 2014 affect exporting netlogo logged data?

Tags: logging, applet, netlogo

Before the java update in january 2014, we were able to export students' logged data from a netlogo simulation.

(code in https://gist.github.com/stepheneb/5469959).

However, after the update, it no longer exports the logged data. wondering if this is an encountered problem? is there a fix to this? 
thank you!

Comment: I'm going to guess that this probably involves JavaScript code in a web page talked to an embedded NetLogo applet via LiveConnect? Assuming my guess is correct: I'm afraid I've never worked with LiveConnect so I know very little about it. Maybe Googling "Java Update 51 LiveConnect" would turn up something?

Comment: Also, when you say "It no longer exports the logged data", do any error messages appear and what do they say exactly? You'd probably need to look for them in two places: in the Java console, and in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1):

This problem had to do with the update. This was fixed by changing the setting:

"permissions": "all-permissions"